# How do I find all XML elements whose value is in a list of values using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I need to be able to find all XML elements whose values can be found in a list of values from another group of XML elements. In other words return all of the elements from group A whose value matches any of the elements from group b. I need to accomplish this using LINQ to XML.

Here's the code. This returns null. How do I fix it?

```
IEnumerable<XElement> MyElements = from e in GroupA.Elements("Element")
         where GroupB.Elements("Element").ToList().Contains(e)
         select e;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problems have you had with your current attempted solutions?

Comment: So, what's stopping you? Get some LINQ to XML tutorial and get to work.

Comment: Tarec, I've been doing just that for the last 2 hours, with no luck, that's why I came here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
IEnumerable<XElement> MyElements = from e in GroupA.Elements("Element")
         where GroupB.Elements("Element").Any(b => b.Value == e.Value)
         select e;
```